# @ServerEndpoint can be an EJB but can not be plain CDI bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi, ejb-3.1

I've just got a following problem and can not figure out an answer:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket/server")
public class ServerUpdateEndpoint implements Serializable {
    ...@OnOpen, OnMessage OnClose annoted methods, works fine...

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "ServerUpdateEndpoint start");
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stop() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "ServerUpdateEndpoint stop");
    }

}
```

When I annotate this class with @Named lifecycle callbacks @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy never gets executed.

When I annotate this with @Singleton it works fine.

Can anyone explain, what the problem with plain CDI annotations here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely can have CDI annotations only.  You'll need to annotate it `@ApplicationScoped` and ensure that a client connects to the endpoint.  Were you giving it a scope when you added `@Named`?

Comment: On tomEE it does not wor when annotated with @ApplicationScoped, but works fine with EJB annotations

Comment: @TomaszGawel that sounds like a TomEE specific issue.  Is that why this was downvoted?

Comment: You're right, but I cannot uncheck it until you modify the anser. So maybe add a notice about TomEE and I will withdraw the vote? OK?

Comment: TomEE doesn't support WebSockets as of when I posted this answer - a year ago.